# CouchDB plugin for Wireshark?

Tags: wireshark, couchdb

I am trying to understand [CouchDB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Couchdb) network traffic with [Wireshark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireshark) and find it very difficult.

A simple transaction with plain-text content seems to result in many lines in Wireshark, most of them being not more than unparsed binary data:

```
44270 > terabase [PSH ACK] Seq=1411 Ack=2369 Win=16195 Len=27 [...]
00:00:00:1b:00:00:2a:6b:00:10:03:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:1c:00:00:00:00:03:21:00:1e
```

Packet data is decoded up to the TCP level, but not at the CouchDB level.

Is there any Wireshark plugin to understand CouchDB traffic ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CouchDB traffic is just HTTP traffic to a JSON API; even if Wireshark doesn't catch the fact that it's HTTP, the traffic should still be really quite readable.

A TCP ACK packet (the one pasted in your question) is never going to be terribly enlightening, though; you're interested in the data within the TCP connection.  Try right-clicking one of the packets and "Follow TCP stream" - a window will come up with all of the data from the connection, color-coded by request and response.

Comment: +1. What I do is go into the Wireshark config in the http protocol, and add `5984` in the list of ports. Then Wireshark will provide further parsing, showing HTTP verbs, responses, etc.